# SharePoint Designer 2010 sends email to shared mailbox but can't send it to individual users

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, email, sharepoint-email

I created a workflow in SP Designer 2010. I want it to sends email to both shared mailbox and individual mailbox. However, the workflow only works for shared mailbox, but NOT individual. Is there any I can do to fix it without writing code?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Whether you want members of shared mailbox can also receive the email from workflow?

It's by default, only the shared mailbox can receive the emails. Members can view the email from shared mailbox folder.

If you want to send to individual users, you can create a mail-enabled security group, add users to this group, then send email to this group.